# Python while key pressed function

Tags: python, python-curses

I recently built an robot that's working with the Raspberry Pi 3 B. I have made a script for it to move forward, backward, left/right with some functions.

```
import curses
#some more code#
while True:
    char = screen.getch()
    if char == ord('q'):
        break
    elif char == ord('w'):
        goForward()
    elif char == ord('s'):
        goBack()
    elif char == ord('d'):
        goRight()
    elif char == ord('a'):
        goLeft()
    elif char == ord('e'):
         goStop()
```

When I want to turn left, I press `a` and it turns forever until I press something else or `stop("e")`. I want to know if there's a way to rewrite this script so that when I press, for example, `d` to turn right while `d` is pressed and then stop when the key is released. Just like toy cars. Like:

```
while(d.key_pressed == 1):
    goRight()
```

Comment: how about setting a flag. sort of 1 or 0. if the key is pressed, then you set it's value to 1 while the others are left as 0.

Comment: Did you try the `nodelay` function to allow non blocking key behaviour? You would read the key value and consider it a key repeat until the value returned by `getch` returned to -1.